# Zoom meeting for Windows 10. Can not find record

Tags: zoom-meeting

During a Zoom meeting I pressed alt + r, there was a question if I would like to record. My answer was "yes". After this another person (who created meeting) have got request if he agree to record and answered "yes" as well. After I saw notification that recording was accepted.

Conference finished in 40 min (it was non paid account\conference). And I can not find any record now.

I was checking through standard folder for recordings on my computer, checking current path through Zoom application, checking saved videos from Zoom program. Also I was searching in downloads, documents, videos on my computer.

I have Windows 10 OS

Where else I can look for the record? Is it possible that the record is on computer of another person?